# pass a parameter to a python function in jinja

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

i have this little issue:

I cannot figure how to give a parameter to a python function inside the jinja scope on onclick function.
to explain it better here an example.

Python code (the demineur.onclick function need the x and y values but i cant give them a key argument inside the render)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
import demineur
@app.route('/')
def keyIt():
   return render_template('demineur.html',cc=demineur.onclick(x,y)) #i know i cant do that but that what i want to do in reality so i let like that
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

how i want to give the x and y arguments for the python function (there are the i and j ones)
HTML

```
   window.onload=function(){
    tab=document.createElement("table")
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        row=tab.insertRow(0)
        for (j=0;j<20;j++){
            cell=row.insertCell(0)
            cell.id=i+j
            cell.setAttribute("onclick","{{cc("+i+","+j+")}}")
        }
    }
    grille=document.getElementById("grille")
    if (!grille.hasChildNodes()) {
        grille.appendChild(tab);
    };
```

So to pass them to the python function i cant declare the function with directly the x and y parameters because jinja haven't this integrated and i dont want to bother with route because there are simple x and y coordonate and i dont need a fancy thing.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the `x,y` arguments in the request.

In case of `GET` request you can access them with

```
    x = request.args.get("x")
```

In case of `POST` request use

```
    x = = request.form.get("x")
```

For details, see the [flask.Request documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request)

Comment: I dont understand, i dont post anything, i just want to call a function inside the py file, and even with that (x and y are now defined) i get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__call__' wich is related to the onclick attribute that doesn't get the function call